# Finding area of a triangle in a quadralateral with only one side known

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry, angle

> For a quadrilateral $PQRS$, $PR=40$ and $PS=32$. Suppose for a point $X$ on the line segment $RS$ the triangles $PQX$ and $PRS$ are congruent in that order. If area of triangle $PXS$ is $112$ square units, find area of the triangle $QRX$.

I firstly noted that $PQRX$ is cyclic. Then used $\frac12ab\sin\theta$ for areas thrice and got some equations, which seem to be very messy to work with. And also I am one equation short (I took 2 sides and 3 angles as new variables).

Any help to proceed?

Comment: Welcome! Please show what you've tried.

Comment: yes..i firstly noted that pqrx is cyclic. then used 1/2 ab sin theta for areas thrice and got some equations..which seem to be very messsy to work with..and also i am one equation short(i took 2 sides and 3 angles as new variables

Comment: Could you add a diagram and put your attempt (your comment above + your equations) into the post? Then your question will be well received and people will be interested in writing an answer.